# Python - Function not updating

Tags: python, function, scipy, numeric

I've been facing strange results in a numerical problem I've been working on and since I started to program in python recently, I would like to see if you can help me.

Basically, the program has a function that is minimized for different values in a nested loop. I'll skip the details of the function for simplicity but I checked it several times and it is working correctly. Basically, the code looks like that:

```
def function(mins,args):
    #I'll skip those details for simplicity
    return #Value

ranges = ((0+np.pi/100),(np.pi/2-np.pi/100),np.pi/100)
while Ri[0] < R:
    Ri[1] = 0; Ri[n-1] = R-(sum(Ri)-Ri[n-1])
    while Ri[1] < (R-Ri[0]):
        res = opt.brute(function, ranges, args=[args], finish=None)
        F = function(res,args)
        print(f'F = {F}')
        Ri[1] += dR
        Ri[2] = R-(sum(Ri)-Ri[n-1])
    Ri[0] += dR
```

So, ignoring the `Ri[]` meaning in the loop (which is a variable of the function), for every increment in Ri[] the program makes a minimization of `mins` by the `scipy.optimize.brute` obtaining `res` as the answer, then it should run the function with this answer and print the result `F`. The problem is that it always get the same answer, no matter what the parameters I get in the minimization (which is working fine, I checked). It's strange because if I get the values from the minimization (which is an n-sized array, being `n` an input) and create a new program to run the same function and just get the result of the function, it returns me the right answer.

Anyone can give me a hint why I'm getting this? If I didn't make myself clear please tell and I could provide more details about the function and variables. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the code you shared, it looks like `res` and `F` are not further used within the while loop (unless `args` somehow depends on `Ri`?).

Comment: They should be used every time the loop goes, I mean, every time I update the `Ri` values, I want to obtain `res` by the minimization and use it to calculate `F`. The problem is that even tough `res` is different every time, I always get the same `F`

Comment: But why is `res` different every time? According to the code you shared, it's the same every time. Only `Ri` changes.

Comment: The function depends on `Ri`, I forgot to mention it

Comment: So, `args` depends on `Ri`? Could you clarify the dependence in your code above?

Comment: Yes, it does. `res` depends since the function also depends. If you want I can share the whole code so you can try to run it.

Comment: You don't have to show all the code, but you do need to show enough so we can see what depends on what.  Often we ask for [mcve].  If `function` some how uses `Ri` or `F` from the calling environment, you should show that.  Better yet make those values part of `args`.  That's the purpose of `args` - to pass values to the function that might vary from call to call.  Another thing we don't know is how sensitive `function` is to the inputs.  Maybe the `min` is always `0`, regardless of `res` and `args`.  If you want help, you have to provide enough information (but not too much!).